# How to mutate a reactive value in script logic and have it update the DOM, in Vue.js 3 Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I’m making a simple component (SFC) that cycles through a list of strings and replaces the text in a heading with the value.

I’m planning on using the composition API for all of my components as I prefer the structure and design.

I thought I had made my component correctly, but it doesn’t auto update in the DOM.

The logs correctly show the values updating, but after setup() is called initially, the value never changes.

Composition API Style (Doesn't update DOM):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ text }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default {
  props: {
    textList: Array,
    interval: Number
  },

setup(props) {
    let text = ref(props.textList[0]);
    let cycler;

    function startCycling() {
      let index = 0;
      text = props.textList[index];
      cycler = setInterval(() => {
        if (index >= props.textList.length) {
          index = 0;
        }

        console.log("Index: " + index);
        text = props.textList[index];

        console.log("Text: " + text);
        index++;
      }, props.interval);
    }

    function stopCycling() {
      clearInterval(cycler);
    }

    startCycling();

    return { text, startCycling, stopCycling };
  }
};
</script>
```

I wondered whether I had made a mistake with my code logic, so I created the same component with the Options API and it worked immediately:

Options API style (Works):

```
export default {
  props: {
    textList: Array,
    interval: Number
  },

  data() {
    return {
      text: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    startCycling: function() {
      let index = 0;
      this.text = this.$props.textList[index];

      cycler = setInterval(() => {
        if (index >= this.$props.textList.length) {
          index = 0;
        }

        console.log("Index: " + index);
        this.text = this.$props.textList[index];

        console.log("Text: " + this.text);
        index++;
      }, this.$props.interval);
    },

    stopCyling: function() {
      clearInterval(cycler);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.startCycling();
  },
}
```

How do I replicate this functionality in Vue's new Composition API?

What do I need to do to `text`, to allow me to change it in code and maintain reactivity?
Simply using `ref(text)` and returning this, doesn’t seem to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call `startCycling();` in  `onMounted` hook

```
 onMounted(() => {
      startCycling();
    })
```

but you have to import that hook as you did with `ref` :

```
 import { ref,onMounted } from "@vue/composition-api";
```

When you want to update a variable created using ref you should mutate its value like

`text.value = props.textList[index];`

full code  :

```
<script>
import { ref,onMounted  } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default {
  props: {
    textList: Array,
    interval: Number
  },

setup(props) {
    const text = ref(props.textList[0]);
    let cycler;

    function startCycling() {
      let index = 0;
      text.value = props.textList[index];
      cycler = setInterval(() => {
        if (index >= props.textList.length) {
          index = 0;
        }

        console.log("Index: " + index);
        text.value = props.textList[index];

        console.log("Text: " + text);
        index++;
      }, props.interval);
    }

    function stopCycling() {
      clearInterval(cycler);
    }

     onMounted(() => {
      startCycling();
    })

    return { text, startCycling, stopCycling };
  }
};
</script
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but this doesn't solve the issue. The variable `text` does update, as the console.logs show, but the DOM does not update.

Comment: when you want to update a variable created using ref you should use value `text.value = props.textList[index];`